# Writing Jasmine Test for State having PreparedQueryOptions

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am writing jasmine test case for state in angular JS.

My state has resolve section something like this.

```
resolve: {
             myResult: function () {
                 var dfd = $q.defer();
                 var queryOptions = new PreparedQueryOptions().$expand(["children"]).effectivity(myPredicate);
                 //Rest of the code
                 return dfd.promise;
             }
         }
```

Here I extended PreparedQueryOptions to add effectivity method in it.
Now from my test case when I made following call

```
myState.definition.resolve.myResult();
```

Its throwing error as "effectivity is not a function". But $expand is getting executed properly.

PreparedQueryOptions don't have this method, but I added this and its working properly (without any errors).

How to solve thise problem? Should I write Spy on these method and how?

Comment: Does this statement work in your app? If so, you porbably aren't including your modifications to `PreparedQueryOptions` correctly in your tests

Comment: Call from my test directly calls myState resolve function. So is it necessary to include PreparedQueryOptions in my test case.

Comment: You said "Here I extended PreparedQueryOptions to add effectivity method in it", did you include you extension in addition to PreparedQueryOptions?

Comment: Sorry I am not getting what you are suggesting, but in my code I added effectivity method and its working properly. In my test case though I did not write any code related to PreparedQueryOptions. I just called my resolved function from test case. Hope this explained everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you are testing calls an extension you wrote for `PreparedQueryOptions`. If you haven't included that extension to your testing framework, then your test will fail since that extension will be called and will be undefined.

Since you aren't testing either `PreparedQueryOptions` or the extension, I would suggest stubbing them out for your test cases. If you are using Jasmine, you could do something like this:

```
var PreparedQueryOptions = jasmine.createSpy('PreparedQueryOptions');
PreparedQueryOptions.$extend = jasmine.createSpy('$extend');

//return empty object so that queryOptions variable will be defined
PreparedQueryOptions.$extend.effectivity = function() { return {}};
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but still its trowing same error